# Is it possible to change the Windows 7 display scaling without logging out?

Tags: windows-7, dpi, scaling

In Windows 7 and 10 (possibly in earlier versions as well), you can change how the DPI scaling for your desktop, essentially "magnifying" items on the screen. In Windows 7, this option can be found under Control Panel > Display like so:

[image]

Modifying this setting requires the user to log out and back in before taking effect, but we find that the hardware profiles for tablets are automatically setting it to 150%, which causes issues with some legacy applications we use. We also have a few users that keep their scaling at 150% for visibility reasons.

I'm currently tasked with either A) finding a way to make this change more convenient for the user, or B) completely redesigning the way the applications handle scaling. For obvious reasons, I'd much rather do option A if it's available. If I can change the scaling programmatically for the app's purposes, then back without user intervention, that would be ideal as well. Unable, I've been unable to find out how this feature actually works, and/or why it requires a logout.

**Is it possible to change the Windows 7 display scaling without logging out?**

Comment: nope only works starting 8.1 because here a message that added to notity programs that the DPI has changed

Answer (score 1):

**No.**
as microsoft official pages say, but **Yes** as programs go

In windows 10 you can only change to presets, but need to log out when you change to something other. So there your problem would be solved, but you are on 7, so:

There is [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/text_resize), but beware if it makes something crash or causes bluescreen. That's why you are "required" to log out.

[Also a Reddit thread about same problem (no solve from there)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/35wayw/possible_to_change_dpi_without_logging_out/)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Frogot to mention, that I am curious of every vote, if you voter could explain, why did you vote that way. ;)